# Getting number of disk accesses from BufferedStream

Tags: c#, bufferedstream, disk-access

I'm reading a binary file using `BinaryReader`. I want to count the number of disk accesses when buffering input with `BufferedStream`. Unfortunately this class is sealed, so I can't override method to count it manually.

Is there any way of doing it using standard library? Or must I write my own buffering BinaryReader to achieve this?

Comment: Data could be cached in user space, in OS, in disk controller. I don't think you can get other than a rough estimation

Comment: @L.B: OK, let's assume that every refill of buffer is one disk access. So how to count this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just calculate it from the buffer size you specified in the BufferedStream(Stream, int) constructor.  The default is 4096 bytes.  Assuming you don't Seek(), the number of file accesses is `(filesize + bufsize - 1) / bufsize`.

A total overkill approach is to keep in mind that you can chain streams.  Create your own Stream derived class and just count the number of calls to the Read() method that need to supply data from the underlying stream.  Pass an instance of that class to the BufferedStream constructor.

Neither approach lets you find out how often the operating system hits the disk driver and physically transfers data from the disk.  The file system cache sits in between and the actual number greatly depends on how the file data is mapped across the disk cylinders and sectors.  You'd get info about that from a performance counter.  There's little point in actually using it, the numbers you get will very poorly reproduce on another machine.

Comment: That's the way of thinking, I was looking for! Works greatly.

I will use it in my academic project only to simulate working with pages on hard drive, when demonstrating various merge sort algorithms. So this solution is good enough.